# Before trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I'm creating my first trigger in **sql server 2008**. I have two tables, `employee` and `employee_audit`.

1. `employee` table have three fields `empno` (*auto increment*), `first_name`  and `last_name`
2. `employee_audit` table have `empno` (*auto increment*) last_name.

I want to create trigger on `employee` and update its last name and before update this last name I want to store `employee` table's `last_name` in `employees_audit` table's last_name

```
create trigger before_employee_update
on employee
after update
as 
declare @last_name varchar(20)
select @last_name = i. last_name from inserted i;
Begin 
Insert into employees_audit(last_name) 
values(@last_name);
end;
```

what I have to write instead of "after"
cz I first want to store the old last_name value in employees_audit table and then want to update last_name value in employee

and before is not recognized trigger in sql server

Comment: so where can we start tracing?

Comment: but according to the fields you mention there is no `last_name` in `empoyee_audit` table.

Comment: Please post what you have tried out so far.